# At what point can Approach mode be engaged in an A320?

Tags: airbus-a320, approach, autopilot, precision-approach

In my experience using Flightgear and other computer simulators, when flying an ILS approach on an A320, the approach mode can only be engaged at a certain point or later. What is this point, and why is it used?

Comment: Is this experience in a "game" simulation, a real simulator, or the real world?

Comment: Updated post based on comment.

Comment: I wondered if it was a game - that often means great simplification from Bianfable's answer, for example Infinite Flight allows engaging APPR mode at <=200KIAS and NAV1 tuned.

Comment: Yeah, it's FlightGear, and the aircraft itself is pretty accurate, with majority of systems (fuel, hydraulic, bleed, electrical) working. MCDU is also probably 80-90% functional. I'd say it is one of the better computer simulators out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions for arming the ILS APPR mode are given in the FCOM:

> **Arming Conditions**
>
> The pilot arms the (ILS) APPR mode (LOC and G/S in blue on the FMA) by pushing the APPR
> pushbutton on the FCU, provided that:
>
> - An ILS approach is selected,
> - The aircraft is above 400 feet RA,
> - The ILS and RA are available,
> - Go-around or takeoff or final mode is not engaged,
> - ILS frequency and course are identically set on both receivers.

<sup>([Airbus A320 FCOM - Autoflight](http://www.smartcockpit.com/aircraft-ressources/A320-Autoflight.html) - Flight Guidance)</sup>

These are just the technical limitations for when you *can* arm the APPR mode, not when you *should*. The FCTM has some more details on that:

> **INTERCEPTION OF FINAL APPROACH COURSE**
>
> When cleared for the ILS, the APPR pb should be pressed. This arms the approach
> mode and LOC and GS are displayed in blue on the FMA. At this stage the second
> AP, if available, should be selected.
>
> If the ATC clears for a LOC capture only, the crew will press LOC p/b on the FCU.
> If the ATC clears for approach at a significant distance, e.g. 30 nm, the crew should
> be aware that the G/S may be perturbed and CAT 1 will be displayed on FMA till a
> valid Radio Altimeter signal is received.
>
> [...]
>
> **MISCELLANEOUS**
>
> The ILS or LS PB is to be checked pressed in the first stage of the approach. The
> crew will check that
>
> - LOC and GS scales and deviations are displayed on PFD
> - IDENT is properly displayed on the PFD. If no or wrong ident displayed, the crew
>   will check the audio ident.

<sup>(Airbus A320 FCTM - Normal Operations - ILS Approach)</sup>